# Calling RegisterAsyncTask on an async method

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous

I posted a previous problem ([asp.net UpdatePanel with UserControls and Page Level Async Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285371/asp-net-updatepanel-with-usercontrols-and-page-level-async-method)), and think I have narrowed down my issue to a separate question.

I have an asp.net page, which needs to call an async method from a library.

I load the page as follows:

```
Private _dlgt As AsyncTaskDelegate
Protected Delegate Sub AsyncTaskDelegate()

 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
    Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf OnBegin, AddressOf OnEnd, AddressOf OnTimeout, "AsyncTask1", True)
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadTask)
End Sub

Public Function OnBegin(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs, ByVal cb As AsyncCallback, ByVal extraData As Object) As IAsyncResult
    _dlgt = New AsyncTaskDelegate(AddressOf Update)
    Dim result As IAsyncResult = _dlgt.BeginInvoke(cb, extraData)
    Return result
End Function

Private Async Function Update() As Task
    Dim AController As New CIP_WS.ARFController
    Dim ARFTask As Task(Of CIP_WS.ARF) = AController.GetARFWithResultsAsync(Client.ClientID, PRN, Nothing, StartTime, EndTime, CIP_WS.LabResultController.InequalityModes.AsIs)
    ARF = Await ARFTask
    PrintResults()
End Function
```

The problem (I think), is that I have to set the page attribute to async=true, as I need to await a task.  However (according to MS), if i set the attribute to true, the whole page will be processed asynchronously.  If set to false, "the thread that executes the page will be blocked until all asynchronous tasks are complete".  The latter is what I need, as it is loading and displaying the page, before the data (i.e before the update async method returns), and I am only getting placeholders.

To be clear, the Update method never completes.  The Page_Load always complete without await the method to finish.

I feel so close, but far on getting this to work now.  Any help, much appreciated.

EDIT____

Firstly thanks for the responses so far.

I have tried the following code previously and it 90% works, but thanks for the suggestion.

```
    Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf Update)
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadTask)
```

It is probably my own fault, but I have been trying to keep the problem simple, but it is bigger than this.

The code above only 90% works, because it loads the data async fine, and then the page renders and loads as expected.  However, I have some dynamic user-controls, which also load fine initially, but do not behave correctly during postbacks.  In this case, when a user click a button, it does not change the visibility of a panel within the specific user-control.  I have fully documented the issue on the link to another SO question above, but in short it works fine when I do not use async, but not when I have an async call during load.

I moved on to another part of the project , while I took a break from that problem, and started async-ing another part of the site.  Again, I hit more dynamic user-controls, but this time the async call was in the load of the user-control rather than the page.  I had exactly the same issue, except it was a drop down not persisting selections, rather than a panel visibility not persisting.  I figured out I needed to call the asyn method in the following way

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf OnBegin, AddressOf OnEnd, AddressOf OnTimeout, "AsyncTask1", True)
            Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf OnBegin, AddressOf OnEnd, AddressOf OnTimeout, "AsyncTask1", True)

    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadTask)
    Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks()

    PrintGraph()

    End If 
  End Sub
```

It was both manually passing true to force parallel processing, and calling ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks that fixed it for the cuser-ontrols and this page as a whole.  It now works perfectly async.  The only extra thing I did have to do, which effects other async calls in the project was add the following to the config:

```
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="false" />
```

The only bummer with this is, I have to call all PageAsyncTask using the fully overloaded method (onLoad,OnEnd,OnTimeOut,State,Parallel), rather than just passing the main method.  I think due to having to handle the TimeOut manually after adding the key, but I am not sure.

Sooo... I then tried to take this knowledge to help with my original issue, and it is still not having it!

So I can either:

1) Use the following, load the data async, and load the page fine initially, but any postback reverts user-controls back to original state.  This would also have a knock on effect to the other async issue I had, which meant all future async tasks needed to be registered as per item 2, so this would re-break that now working page.

```
    Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf Update)
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadTask)
```

2) Use the following, which does not wait for the registered async method to complete (from what I can tell), so loads the webpage without essentially updating any controls.  As per a comment, I accept there maybe something else wrong, that I have failed to do.

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
     Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf OnBegin, AddressOf OnEnd, AddressOf OnTimeout, "AsyncTask1", True)
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadTask)
    End Sub
```

I can make this work to the same extent as item 1, if I don't use the IAsyncResult approach as per MS docs, and just call the method for OnBegin, but this still has the same issue as 1.

```
     Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
     Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf Update, AddressOf OnEnd, AddressOf OnTimeout, "AsyncTask1", True)
    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadTask)
    End Sub
```

it should be noted I can use the IAsyncResult approach successfully in the other page scenario where the user-control is calling the async load method.

```
    Private _dlgt As AsyncTaskDelegate
    Protected Delegate Sub AsyncTaskDelegate()

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf OnBegin, AddressOf OnEnd, AddressOf OnTimeout, "AsyncTask1", True)

    Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadTask)
    Page.ExecuteRegisteredAsyncTasks()

    PrintGraph()

    End sub 


 Public Function OnBegin(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs, ByVal cb As AsyncCallback, ByVal extraData As Object) As IAsyncResult

    _dlgt = New AsyncTaskDelegate(AddressOf ReLoadSelectors)
    Dim result As IAsyncResult = _dlgt.BeginInvoke(cb, extraData)

    Return result
End Function
```

`3) Load the data synchronous, and everything just works again, including the user-controls persisting their values, but just dead slow.

I am going out of my mind with this one.  Works fine sync for everything, just not async.  Manged to get it to work on one page, where the user-control needs to do the async load call, but cannot make it work on another page, where the page has to do the async load call.  One type of task registration waits for the async data method to return, but the fully overloaded version using IAsyncResult does not.

Please if anyone can spot where I have gone wrong, and put me out of my misery, I would be so grateful.

Comment: How to await Update, before the page loads...

Comment: That's what `Page.RegisterAsyncTask` does. And you're already doing that.

Comment: No it doesn't.  It doesn't wait, it just loads the page, still with placeholders.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "still with place holders" I don't see where you attempt to update anything in the DOM from this code. Perhaps you haven't followed the details for [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I can post a lot more code, i just wanted to keep it as relevant as possible.

Comment: PrintResults(), takes the data from the await ARFTask method, and updates the labels on the page.

Comment: This method never fires, as the page loads before that part of Update() can reaches.

Comment: You haven't shown that in your code. Please review [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: But I have, I have said that the Update() method never completes.  Why do I need to elaborate further on the code that it never reaches?  I am not trying to be difficult, but I am struggling to see why I have not added enough code.  There is no point swamping this page with code that is never reached, surely?

Comment: You have some code that's irrelevant and can be removed, and some that you are missing. What code you need to include is described clearly on [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need the *minimal* amount of code that *completely* demonstrates your issue.

Comment: What is irrelevant???

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerasynctask(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: yes.  I stand my point, you can follow my code to the point it fails.  If you fail to see that, that is not down to me.

Comment: Are you sure you looked at the documentation? The documentation shows to do certain things that you aren't doing, so forgive me for being skeptical.

Comment: why are you attacking my ask for help.  If you don't want to help, that is fine.  I have asked nicely for some help, as I have got stuck, and done my best to concisely portray my issue.   If someone asks for further clarification, of course i will do whatever I can.

Comment: thanks for the down vote, just what someone needs when they are trying to get a difficult issue sorted.

Comment: I'm not sure what why you think I'm not helping you. I'm giving you information that will improve your question, as well as giving you a link to the documentation that describes exactly what you need to do. That documentation has code examples that show how to execute the tasks, and you are not doing that in your own code.

Comment: `The latter is what I need, as it is loading and displaying the page... and I am only getting placeholders.` That's not how asynchronous pages work. They will only send the HTTP response once your asynchronous methods complete. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: @StephenCleary - Thanks.  I have no doubt I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to set Page.Async to true in order to use RegisterAsyncTask. All the registered tasks are guaranteed to finish before page prerender event.

what's the definition of AsyncTaskDelegate? Why not use PageAsyncTask.ctor(Func handler) ? Something like below.

```
Dim LoadTask As New PageAsyncTask(AddressOf Update)
Page.RegisterAsyncTask(LoadTask)
```